# nice way to kill piped process?

Tags: shell, process, pid, tail, sh

I want to process each stdout-line for a shell, the moment it is created. I want to grab the output of `test.sh` (a long process). My current approach is this:

```
 ./test.sh >tmp.txt &
 PID=$!
 tail -f tmp.txt | while read line;  do
 echo $line
 ps ${PID} > /dev/null
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     echo "exiting.."
 fi
 done;
```

But unfortunately, this will print "exiting" and then wait, as the tail -f is still running. I tried both `break` and `exit`

I run this on FreeBSD, so I cannot use the `--pid=` option of some linux tails.

I can use `ps` and `grep` to get the pid of the tail and kill it, but thats seems very ugly to me.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you need the `tail` process?

Could you instead do something along the lines of

```
./test.sh | while read line; do
  # process $line
done
```

or, if you want to keep the output in tmp.txt :

```
./test.sh | tee tmp.txt | while read line; do
  # process $line
done
```

If you still want to use an intermediate `tail -f` process, maybe you could use a named pipe (fifo) instead of a regular pipe, to allow detaching the `tail` process and getting its pid:

```
./test.sh >tmp.txt &
PID=$!

mkfifo tmp.fifo
tail -f tmp.txt >tmp.fifo &
PID_OF_TAIL=$!
while read line; do
  # process $line
  kill -0 ${PID} >/dev/null || kill ${PID_OF_TAIL}
done <tmp.fifo
rm tmp.fifo
```

I should however mention that such a solution presents several heavy problems of race conditions :

- the PID of `test.sh` could be reused by another process;
- if the `test.sh` process is still alive when you read the last line, you won't have any other occasion to detect its death afterwards and your loop will hang.

Comment: I feel really stupid now, as the first solution obviously works. I am relatively new to shell-scripting, and did not realize that the first solution you mentioned does not block.. Thanks!